# OKI ES8453 MFP printer scan to shared folder error

Tags: windows, networking, server, printing, cifs

I´ve tried to scan a file on my OKI printer to a share folder in my PC, Windows 10, set up a profile, URL of shared folder with local IP address, CIFS protocol, port 445 and credentials of an administrator. However, every time I scan the file the printer fails to connect to the server and cancels the scan.

I tried to do it again with a diferent profile but the same thing happens over and over.
I search the Internet to see if anyone came up with a solution to this problem but there was no luck.